# R panel time series mean plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, panel, mean

I have panel data with ID=1,2,3... year=2007,2008,2009... and a factor foreign=0,1, and a variable X.

I would like to create a time series plot with x-axis=year, y-axis=values of X that compares the average (=mean) development of each factor over time. As there are 2 factors, there should be two lines, one solid and one dashed.

I assume that the first step involves the calculation of the means for each year and factor of X, i.e. in a panel setting. The second step should look something like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=MEAN(X), group=Foreign, linetype=Foreign))+geom_line()+theme_bw()
```

Many thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` to calculate the means:

```
library(dplyr)

# generate some data (because you didn't provide any, or any way or generating it...)
data = data.frame(ID = 1:200, 
                  year = rep(1951:2000, each = 4), 
                  foreign = rep(c(0, 1), 100), 
                  x = rnorm(200))

# For each year, and seperately for foreign or not, calculate mean x.
data.means <- data %>% 
                group_by(year, foreign) %>%
                summarize(xmean = mean(x))

# plot. You don't need group = foreign
ggplot(data.means, aes(x = year, y = xmean, linetype = factor(foreign))) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot2 lineplot]

Comment: No problem! If it answers your question you could upvote the answer and/or accept it.